# Assimilating WebApi Controller in MVC 5 Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am proficient in MVC 5 but web api 2 is new to me. I am trying to add a webapi controller to my MVC Project, But I can't access It's path.
Iv'e added a web api controller in a new Folder called webapi, and the name of the controller is searchcontroller, Inside My MVC 5 Project.
I can't access it's path, something that should be:
/api/search/get.
I think It might be with something with my App Start in Global Ajax :

Help Please!
Here is the code in the app start :

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ApiById",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
    );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ApiByName",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}",
                defaults: null,
                constraints: new { name = @"^[a-z]+$" }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ApiByAction",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { action = "Get" }
            );
        });
```

The controller code :

```
 public class WebAPISearchReultsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<ICE.Logic.ArticleSearchResult> Get(string searchQuery)
    {
        return SearchLogic.Instance.GetArticleSearchResults(searchQuery);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your controller look like? or is this the part you can't actually do?

Comment: Iv'e added the controller code in the original post

Comment: Did you try adding webapi to your MVC project from Nuget or added manually? Adding from Nuget would help you keep things in place properly like routing templates etc.

Comment: Iv'e added manually : This is what I did : I added a new folder in the root, called it WebAPI and added a WebAPI controller inside this new folder

Comment: I would advise you to use nuget. There are lots of settings involved in the web.config that affect this.

Comment: I'm more familiar with MVC than Web API so maybe I'm missing something...but wouldn't the URI "/api/search/get" try to find a controller called 'SearchController'?

Comment: @user3722546 Also are you trying to access: "/api/search/get" or "/api/webapisearch/get" ? Because your controller name is not just "Search" but its "webapisearch". And are you getting 404 when calling the api?

Comment: try using `/api/WebAPISearchReults?searchQuery=test`

Answer (score 0):

I would construct the API method like this...

```
[Route("api/webapisearchreults")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]string searchQuery)
{
   var data = SearchLogic.Instance.GetArticleSearchResults(searchQuery);
   var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
   return response;
 }
```

You could then check the data and if there's no data or an exception etc you can inspect the `HttpStatusCode` returned.  You can set the [status code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx), to something meaningful.

**EDIT**: WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Well What about accessing the webapi? Do I need to do anything in the global.asax?

Comment: No, just add the WebAPI package via NuGet and that's all you need. Check that you have the WebApiConfig too (*see edit*)